# How to wake up iPhone app from watchOS 2?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I have an app that has a very rich network layer and my apple watch app depends on all the models. Unfortunately the app is not modular enough to make this layer available in the watch app.

I solved this problem by using openParentApplication: to wake up the iPhone app, perform the request and give back the results.

In watchOS 2 this method is gone and I should use WatchConnectivity. The best way to use this would be by sending userInfo dictionaries.

But how can I wake up the iPhone app to handle my requests? To get notifications about new userInfos I have to use the WCSessionDelegate and for that I need a WCSession object. But when should I create that? And how to wake up the app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I asked an Apple Engineer about this and got the following tip: The iOS-App should be started in a background-task. So the following worked for me pretty well:

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
dispatch_block_t endBlock = ^ {
    if (identifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        [application endBackgroundTask:identifier];
    }
    identifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
};

identifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:endBlock];
```

Add this to your `session:didReceiveMessage:` or `session:didReceiveMessageData:` method to start a background task with a three minute timeout.

Comment: I don't understand "about start a background task with a 3 minute timeout" can you explain?

Comment: Yeah, the method "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:" starts a background task with the default time out of 3 minutes. According to Apple this is the way we should start them.

Comment: So if I want to open app on iPhone from Watch it will opened after 3 min?

Comment: No, you can't open the app in the foreground. This will open the iPhone app in the background and if no other request comes in the background task will be terminated after 3 minutes by the system.

Comment: Is there official answer that it is not possible to open the app in the foreground from watch os2?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find it right now but I remember a document for watchOS 1 where Apple described that it is forbidden to open the iPhone app in the foreground. But technically it is possible by calling openURL in the iPhone app.

Comment: This is interesting. So basically, to keep the app open while you're doing stuff, you need to schedule a background task? Usually, Apple gives you a few seconds after it just woke you up. I haven't seen this documented elsewhere.

Comment: Using WatchConnectivity, when your iOS app is woken in the background using sendMessage from the WatchKit extension you do seem to get a good 10 seconds of runtime or until you reply to the sendMessage that woke the app, it seems.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Since I do some network-requests, it's not guaranteed that the task is done 10 sec later...

Comment: How is it possible to launch iOS app from the watch 3 app?

Comment: Hi, can somebody translate it to swift?

Comment: @S.Wei this was already translated to Swift, please take a look in the answers below.

Comment: From what I've learned empirically - expirationHandler was executed immedietely after I'd started it (tested that attaching debuger to iOS app). If you wanna execute any async code you should use `BackgroundFetch`

Answer (score 6):

Swift version of Benjamin Herzog's suggestion below.  Of note, while I did choose to push the work initiated by the Watch to a background task, as long as my app was in the background, the system woke it up just fine.  Doing the work in a background task did not appear to be required, but is best practice.

```
override init() {
    super.init()
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        session = WCSession.defaultSession()
        session.delegate = self
        session.activateSession()
    }
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        let taskID = self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()
        //Do work here...
        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID)
    })
    var replyValues = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
    let status = "\(NSDate()): iPhone message: App received and processed a message: \(message)."
    print(status)
    replyValues["status"] = status
    replyHandler(replyValues)
}

func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({})
}

func endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(taskID)
}
```

Comment: Sorry for asking but, what kind of work is supposed to be done in `//Do work here...` ?

Comment: This is where you would put your code you want to execute after waking up the device.

Comment: ah ok, then i just misunderstood the sample code a bit.. :) , i got a bit confused since you called `replyHandler()` "earlier".

Answer (score 5):

In the WatchKit extension you will want to use the WatchConnectivity [WCSession sendMessage](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:) APIs. In the extension check that the iOS app is reachable, and then send the message:

```
let session = WCSession.defaultSession();
if session.reachable {
    let message = ["foo":"bar"]
    session.sendMessage(message, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
        print("send failed with error \(error)")
    })
}
```

This message will cause the system to wake the iOS app in the background, so make sure to set up the WCSession in a piece of the iOS app code that gets called when running in the background (as an example: you don't want to put it in a UIViewController's subclass's viewDidLoad) so that the message is received. Since you will be requesting some information you might want to take advantage of the reply block.

So this is how you accomplish launching the iOS app in the background, though the WatchConnectivity WWDC session recommended trying to use the "background" transfer methods if possible. If your watch app is read-only then you should be able to queue up any changes on the iOS device using the background transfers and then they will be delivered to the watch app next time it runs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the API of WatchConnectivity was not the problem, but the background task. (See my answer above)

Comment: Actually, according the docs, this is all you need to do to start the iOS app in the background and become automatically reachable (no check needed). Once you ping it once using sendMessage, you can send userInfos or applicationContexts the normal way. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler: - "Calling this method from your WatchKit extension while it is active and running wakes up the corresponding iOS app in the background and makes it reachable."

Comment: It doesn't launch anything on watchOS 3. `session.reachable` is NO.

Comment: On the watch side reachable is generally only YES when the watch app is running in the foreground

Comment: I mean that the code doesn't launch iOS app when running on watchOS 3.

Comment: I can get reply from iOS app using this method, although the app isn't launched (maybe it is in background but the app isn't in app list).

Comment: Yea, it launches in the background