# Wake up the iOS app through Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, apple-watch

I have developed a Apple Watch app to work with the iOS companion app and everything works fine when the iOS app is on either in the foreground or background. And what I'm trying to do now is I want the Apple Watch app to wake up the terminated iOS app to background to perform some simple task, then the iOS app can go back to terminate state again. To do this, I have tried the following:

```
import WatchConnectivity

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, WCSessionDelegate{

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        if(WCSession.isSupported()){
            session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()

        }
    }
    self.saveContext()
}

func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
  startUpCentralManager()
}

}
```

but, nothing happens after I manually kill the apps. Can someone advise me which part I have missed out? I have set BackGround modes in both plist and apps capabilities.

UPDATE:
I'm now able to wake up the app from terminate to background and connect to the device. But I wonder why I could not send the message with the following lines of codes:

```
var outbuffer1 = [UInt8]()
outbuffer1.append(0x01)
outbuffer1 += [UInt8](selectedPassword.utf8)
let data1 = NSData(bytes: outbuffer1, length: 7)
connectingPeripheral.writeValue(data1, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
```

Comment: Are you needing to do any tasks on either one as well?

Comment: Check [this anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31790668/1457385)

Comment: @GrantIsom yup i need my iOS app to pair with an external device through CoreBluetooth when receiving a message from apple watch.

Comment: @shallowThought awesome, and S.Wei thanks! Will try that and post any findings. Need to kick off a core data reading, so if that works, that makes my life a lot easier.

Comment: @GrantIsom i have one more question, can i put the session.delegate in the func applicationWillTerminate or should i put them in func applicationDidEnterBackground?

Comment: @GrantIsom i have did some background study about Core Data, if anything i can help you with that?

Comment: How would I trigger a core data fetch from the watch app?

Comment: @GrantIsom Do you mean, you have saved the data into core data, and now you would like to retrieve the data out? am i right?

Comment: Yes, but I want to retrieve it on the watch, or retrieve it and send it to the watch.

Comment: @GrantIsom sorry for late reply, if you wish to retrieve core data refer as follow, 
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Devices")
        do{
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
            DeviceList.name = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        } catch let error as NSError{
            
        }

Comment: you need an NSManagedObject array to hold the data because the data stored using CoreData is manage by NSManagedObject

Comment: Could you explain how you solve the first part of your question? My iOS application doesn't call the `session:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:`. Do you need to add specific configuration?

Comment: Hi, simply add some code in appDelegate

Comment: I need my iOS app to pair with an external device through CoreBluetooth when receiving a message from apple watch. any update on that? I also need the same if watch app is in the background and detect external device then I need to send the message to ios app to pair with this device.