# Apple Watch & iOS communication with IoT device

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I have IoT Application. And my iPhone app is working with IoT device. I interact with that device from my iPhone app.

Now I am developing Watch application. And I am sending the data to iPhone and (vice-versa) via Watch Connectivity framework to interact with IoT Device.

I have few questions:

1) The above things I do is when the iPhone application is open. What if the user has not started the iPhone app and directly using the watch and want to interact with the IoT device. Can I call API from iOS app even if it's not active? Any limitations if yes?

2) What is the best practice to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

1) No, in order to send data from the Watch to the iPhone using the  `WatchConnectivity` framework, the iOS app needs to be running in the foreground or in the background. If the iOS app is terminated, it cannot receive data from the Watch using the `WatchConnectivity` framework.

2) Without further knowledge about how you connect to your device, I cannot give an answer for sure. In general, the best solution is to communicate directly from the Watch app with the IoT device if you want your Watch app to work even if the phone app hasn't been launched by the user. However, this is not possible in all cases, since your IoT device might be using a protocol for communication that doesn't have a built in/third-party framework available for watchOS. If this is the scenario, you have to rely on the `WatchConnectivity` framework.

Comment: Agree with David, although to item 1, WatchConnectivity is able to wake your app on the iPhone in certain cases (in the background, with proper entitlements.)

Comment: @Cobra no, since watchOS2 the Watch extension cannot wake the iPhone app if it is not running. If it is already running in the background, then `WatchConnectivity` can be used, you are right, but I have mentioned this in my answer as well.

Comment: You cannot wake the iPhone app in the foreground, but you can certainly wake it in the background.  This is the way all watch processing is handled on the iPhone when your iPhone app is not foreground.  Some discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618550/how-to-wake-up-iphone-app-from-watchos-2.  Also, review the Apple Documentation.  One example is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615687-sendmessage.

Comment: You are misunderstanding my answer and the answer in the linked question. If the user never started the app/force quit the iOS app, you have no way to start the iOS app from your Watch app, since you cannot communicate with it using the `WatchConnectivity` framework. If the user has already started your app on iOS, it is not running at the moment in the foreground, but it is still in memory in the background, then you can use `WatchConnectivity`. This is the scenario that is mentioned in the question you linked.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the Apple documentation, but that's ok.  If you implement and test it you will understand.

Comment: @Cobra I am speaking from experience, I have been and am working with the `WatchConnectivity` framework for a while...